# Best design pattern to handle iOS Application State/Data

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I am starting a new project (learning purposes) and I am trying to figure out what is the best software design pattern to use in the following scenario.

I have several data that need to be downloaded from multiple webservices and store somewhere in my app, to display it later. However each piece of data (e.g. list of teachers, students) will only be used in one or more specific view controllers (e.g. teachersViewController and studentsViewController).

I read that the Singleton pattern or use the AppDelegate to store a variable (an object like ApplicationData) is a bad practise, even more in this example which I want to restrict the data access.

So, which design pattern should I choose? I have read something about dependency injection, but I don't have any clue about it or if it even helps me in this question. If it helps, some examples with explanation would be nice.

Comment: Will your app act as a server-client application or you really need to persist all the data (for offline use, for example)?

Comment: Data need to persist.

Comment: Please don't add voting commentary or advice to your posts, that is just like painting a target on your back, as well as not being of any use for most readers. Add it as a comment if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of database to store downloaded data. Good choices are [Realm](https://realm.io) and Core Data. The right way to process data is:

1. Check if data is already in DB and show it if available.
2. Download or update data from server and parse it to objects.
3. Save objects to DB.
4. Show data taken from DB to user.

Download data as needed. When you open VC with students then download only students data and so on.

EDITED: If you need all the data on app open then load it and put in a DB before first screen opens. Then just use DB to show data to user.

Comment: I would like to have the data ready on Application start, since the app have a loading screen. It's a bad user experience to wait for about 20 seconds between segues.

Comment: @Exprove If you use cached data from DB you will only need first time data to be loaded. But if you really load small parts of data more than 20 sec than it is better to load ALL the data on start (but I am afraid it will took much longer than 20 sec). I have edited the answer.

Comment: Are you telling me in each segue to query the database? Wouldn't that be a little slow? Edit: I know there is the prepare method but still is it a good practise?

Comment: @Exprove Querying DB is fast enough to not worry about it. If you doubt you can measure the speed later with Profiler, but I never had such experience. Of course it may happen if your data contains some images or videos saved to DB but it is nonsense.